# Pl/Sql Storing multiple result of select query in single object in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I  have a scenario,a procedure in which there is for loop in which there is a select query which returns different result each time it run. I have to store each and every result in single variable or array or cursor.Please suggest!!.Below provided is the procedure written in a package:

Package Spec:

`TYPE t_product_id IS TABLE OF products.productnr%TYPE
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;`

`TYPE t_product_desc IS TABLE OF varchar(100)
  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;`

`Type t_product_psnr IS TABLE OF prodsubs.PSNR%TYPE 
       INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;`
  `TYPE t_prod_contractperiod IS TABLE OF prodrul.CONTRPEROFPSNR%TYPE 
       INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;`

`Type t_output  IS TABLE OF prodrul.ALLOWEDCUSTTYPES%TYPE
    INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;`

Package body:

```
PROCEDURE x_proc_Validprodcusttypeacctyp (
  i_prodnr        IN      t_product_id,
  i_invoiceprd    IN      prodrul.ALLOWEDINVPERIOD%TYPE,
  i_psnr          IN      t_product_psnr,
  i_contactprd    IN      t_prod_contractperiod,
  i_result        OUT     t_output
```

)

```
IS

BEGIN
  FOR i IN i_prodnr.FIRST .. i_prodnr.LAST

  `LOOP
     BEGIN
            select PRODUCTNR,PRODUCTUSERKEY,ALLOWEDCUSTTYPES,ALLOWEDACCNTTYPES 
            into  i_result (i)`
            from  prodrul rul  join products prods on rul.PRODUCTNROFPSNR = prods.productnr 
            where prods.productnr = i_prodnr (i)   and ALLOWEDINVPERIOD= i_invoiceprd and CONTRPEROFPSNR=  i_contactprd (i)
            and   prods.productnr not in(select productnr from products where SMARTCARDYN = 1)
            and   rul.PRODUCTNROFPSNR not in (select PSPRODUCTNR from prodsubs  join decoders on prodsubs.PSNR = decoders.DECSCPSNR where prodsubs.PSNR= i_psnr (i));
     END;
  END LOOP;


END x_proc_Validprodcusttypeacctyp;
```

Comment: So basically you would like to return an array or collection when you call your procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys_refcursor` as a collection object to return multiple columns instead of using arrays. 
E.g.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE x_proc_validprodcusttypeacctyp (
    i_prodnr        IN   t_product_id,
    i_invoiceprd    IN   prodrul.allowedinvperiod%TYPE,
    i_psnr          IN   t_product_psnr,
    i_contactprd    IN   t_prod_contractperiod,
    i_result            OUT t_output,
    o_cursor            OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN o_cursor FOR
        SELECT  productnr, productuserkey, allowedcusttypes, allowedaccnttypes
          FROM      prodrul rul
                    JOIN
                        products prods
                    ON rul.productnrofpsnr = prods.productnr
         WHERE       prods.productnr = i_prodnr
                    AND allowedinvperiod = i_invoiceprd
                    AND contrperofpsnr = i_contactprd
                    AND prods.productnr NOT IN (SELECT   productnr
                                                            FROM     products
                                                          WHERE  smartcardyn = 1)
                    AND rul.productnrofpsnr NOT IN
                             (SELECT   psproductnr
                                 FROM     prodsubs
                                          JOIN
                                              decoders
                                          ON prodsubs.psnr =
                                                  decoders.decscpsnr
                                WHERE   prodsubs.psnr = i_psnr);
END;
/
```

Comment: I've used that earlier but every time when query runs result gets overriden in cursor and in code it doesnt return any value

Comment: I've used it earlier but each time query runs ,result gets overriden in cursor,so it doesnt return any value then . I just wanted to store each result in a cursor,when select query runs in loop

Comment: @Adi I didn't quite understand as what exactly you mean by results gets overriden? How and where do plan to execute your procedure?

Comment: i have to use for loop as per requirement as for every product number(i_prodnr),there are different result sets returned,and i have to check all those result set

Comment: Hey i want to use that procedure to do validations in my c# code,for ex,like for one productnr there is particular result returned,after that when select query execute for another productnr,the result returned override earlier result present in cursor